# Post data onClick in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, mern

I am trying to post data from `React` to my routers when I click a link,
and then get the data and save them to my `MongoDB`.

But when I click the link it successfully triggers my `function` but then it gives me an error.

This is what I tried: 
Does anyone know what's wrong?

React:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
export default class AddYourAccomodation extends Component {

house = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const house = 'house'
        axios
            .post('/authentication/house', {
                accomcate: house,
            })
            .then(console.log("Posted succesfully"))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
render() {
        return(
            <div>
            <div class="card-group ">
                <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3" id="max-width"> 
                <a href="" onClick={this.house}>
                <div class="card-header text-white"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>  Home</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text text-white">Places like Villa, Castle, Chalet etc.</p>
                </div>
                </a>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>    
       )
    }
}
```

Comment: What error you are encountering ?

Comment: Error: Request failed with status code 404

Comment: it may seem obvious, but the url you are calling is incorrect.

Comment: You are posting to '/authentication/house', Most probably, request is going to localhost:3000/authentication/house assuming your react code is running at localhost:3000. Can you check if axios is properly configured ? 404 means endpoint does not exists.

Comment: No, I have already connected my react with my backend correctly and it's calling the right URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in my router is was getting the wrong URL.

Mistake:

```
app.post('house', (req, res) => {

})
```

Fixed:

```
app.post('/house', (req, res) => {

})
```